# How to maintain the log name for an unhandled exception in Django

Tags: python, django, logging

I am a bit lost about the logging topic.

I declare all my loggers with `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` so when logging I have this info available. However, if an unhandled exception happens, I know that Django logs the exception with log name as `django.request` and so on because of this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/logging/#loggers, but what if I would like to use the log name I have declared? I know I am not actually calling the logger when the exception happens, but I would like to know the originary module for the exception. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't matter what name defined on your `logger` if that particular `logger` not used to log the actual message - that seems to be the case described. If you miss information in the message logged then consider defining [logging formatter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects) to provide missing information in the log message.

Answer (score 0):

The exception should have a traceback printed in the log, even if it was logged against `django.request`, and that should point to where the problem occurred / what it was. Otherwise, you will have to catch the exceptions yourself (in potentially each of your views) and log them as you see fit.